# Controlling computer hardware using Python

Tags: python

I'm a  beginner programmer . I want to build an OS using Python and assembly . And for that I guess I will have to control the hardware. My question is " Is it possible to control computer's hardware parts using python ."

Comment: You say you are beginner to programming and you are trying to build an OS!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10904721/3001761. Maybe start smaller?

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately Python is classified as a [very high level programming
>   language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_high-level_programming_language). It cannot be used, for example, to directly access
>   hardware and perform low-level data structure manipulation. It is
>   completely dependent on something to abstract the hardware from it,
>   and that is the Kernel. It is, however, technically possible to create
>   an operating system centered on Python, that is; have only the very
>   low level stuff in written in C and assembly and have most of the rest
>   of the operating system written in Python.
>
> [This article](http://wiki.osdev.org/Languages) discusses with more detail what languages are
>   suitable for writing operating system kernels.

[More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904721/is-it-possible-to-create-an-operating-system-using-python)